# Google Colab - can't open any notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

After successfully using Google Colab on Chrome for a day the error message pasted below started appearing whenever I try to open any google colab notebook (even the tutorial notebook https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb).

I have deactivated all ad-blockers, tried to reinstall Chrome and tried incognito-mode. I experience the same issue on Firefox but everything seems fine on Edge.

Thanks for any help.

```
Notebook loading error
There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again.
Check dependency list! Synchronous require cannot resolve module 'vs/platform/quickinput/common/quickInput'. This is the first mention of this module!

Check dependency list! Synchronous require cannot resolve module 'vs/platform/quickinput/common/quickInput'. This is the first mention of this module!
Error: Check dependency list! Synchronous require cannot resolve module 'vs/platform/quickinput/common/quickInput'. This is the first mention of this module!
    at s.synchronousRequire (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/js/monaco_editor/vs/loader.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:29:74)
    at i (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/js/monaco_editor/vs/loader.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:35:493)
    at xa.program_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary_l10n__en_gb.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:2359:485)
    at za (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary_l10n__en_gb.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:19:336)
    at xa.next_ (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary_l10n__en_gb.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:17:503)
    at Aa.next (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary_l10n__en_gb.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:20:206)
    at f (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/external_polymer_binary_l10n__en_gb.js?vrz=colab-20210915-060048-RC00_396786732:62:101)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a newly occurring bug being tracked at https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/2250.

I'd recommend following up there with the maintainers in order to accelerate the diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good moment to check out alternatives to Google.

Personally, I would install jupyter locally, but I have been using colab as a way for my 1st year university students to avoid having to install anything on their computer, so I was looking for online solutions. I just created accounts on https://www.kaggle.com/ and https://cocalc.com/ which seem to work pretty much as google's colab. I will check if I can install a similar service on my own service so that I do not depend so much on an external service...

Answer (score -2):

try again with a new email id for google collab and check whether the file is corrupted or unsupported format in drive

Comment: This happens even when opening a NEW notebook or a notebook "example" published by Google...

Comment: This is by far the worst answer that I have ever read on SO. How do you try again with new email when google drive is coupled with your email and many people possibly pay for subscription? This is not 2010 "to just create new email".